# Does. load() load the whole content of the requested page or just a portion?

Tags: jquery, ajax, resources, loading, bandwidth

I am implementing ajax page loading for some parts of my website. I am trying to save some bandwidth and get faster page load times.

I have read that .load() loads the whole content of the page being requested instead of loading only a portion of it. Thus, not saving me any bandwidth, and perhaps not even loading pages faster to the end user.

- Please notice that when I use .load(), I am selecting a portion of the page to be displayed.
- Please keep in mind that my site is for JS and non-JS users.

**1.-** Is it true that .load() loads the whole content of the page even if only a portion is selected to be displayed?

**2.-** If that is true, then, what can I do to load pages via ajax requesting and loading only a portion of the page? Thus saving me some bandwidth.

**3.-** Will this result in faster page loading times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does. load() load the whole content of the requested page or just a portion?

The whole content. The only way to change that would be by changing the server-side code to only return the desired content when it is an ajax request. Ajax requests can be detected by looking for the `x-requested-with` header.

Sample logic would be:

```
isAjax = doesHeaderExist && doesHeaderEqualXHR;
if (!isAjax) {
    include("header.ext");
}
include("page.ext");
if (!isAjax) {
    include("footer.ext");
}
```

Comment: Will this affect non-JS users?

Comment: Nope, since they won't be requesting with ajax.

Comment: Well I have no idea how to do this. What can I put on google to look for more information about it? Is it too complicated? I refer to the server-side of things. I dont want to have two files for each type of user.

Comment: Here's a blog post explaining how to do it in php: http://davidwalsh.name/detect-ajax

Comment: Oh I see, I got confused by a moment. But, is it a most to have two different files? One that has all the content, and the other that has only a part of it?

Comment: Nope, it can all be done with a single file. You use the above if statements to exclude the extra stuff that isn't needed by the ajax requests.

Comment: Great! It worked. Thank you!! This should make pages load faster and save bandwidth, right?